# Use Numba to speed up the Rolling Root Mean Square Deviation Calculation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, numba

I am trying to speed up the Rolling Root Mean Square Deviation Calculation and am stuck with a semi-optimized code. This is my code:

---

Original Root Mean Square Deviation(this function runs fast when n is small, but greatly suffers from large `n` values)

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def rt_mean_sq_dev(array1, array2, n):
    result = np.empty(array1.shape[0])
    result[:n-1] = np.nan

    for i in prange(n-1,array1.shape[0]):
        result[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(array1[i+1-n:i+1] - array2[i]))/n)
    return result
```

---

Semi-optimized Root Mean Square Deviation(constant run-time regardless of the size of `n`

```
@njit  
def rt_mean_sq_dev4(array1, array2, n):
    msd_temp = np.empty(array1.shape[0])

    K = array2[n-1]

    rs_x= array1[0] - K
    rs_xsq = rs_x *rs_x

    msd_temp[0] = np.nan

    for i in range(1,n):#first part of the cumsum for x adn xsq
        rs_x += array1[i] - K
        rs_xsq += np.square(array1[i] - K)
        msd_temp[i] = np.nan

    y_i = array2[n-1] - K
    msd_temp[n-1] = np.sqrt(max(y_i*y_i + (rs_xsq - 2*y_i*rs_x)/n, 0))

    for i in range(n, array1.shape[0]):
        rs_x = array1[i] - array1[i-n]+ rs_x
        rs_xsq = np.square(array1[i] - K) - np.square(array1[i-n] - K) + rs_xsq
        y_i = array2[i] - K

        msd_temp[i] = np.sqrt(max(y_i*y_i + (rs_xsq - 2*y_i*rs_x)/n, 0))

    return msd_temp 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    np.random.seed(0)
    data_size = 200000

    data_c = np.random.uniform(0,1000, size = data_size)+29000
    data_d = data_c  + np.random.uniform(0,1, size = data_size)


    tail = np.tile(30000,200)
    data_c = np.hstack((data_c, tail))
    data_d = np.hstack((data_d, tail))

    N = 3
    test4 = rt_mean_sq_dev4(data_c, data_d,  N )
```

When `n = 7000`, the original function takes about `320ms` per loop while `rt_mean_sq_dev4` merely takes `2.6ms`; when `n = 3` however, the original function takes `1.3ms` and this function stays the same, about `2.5ms`. So overall `rt_mean_sq_dev4` is faster and is preferred.

`rt_mean_sq_dev4` is so far my best attempt at the problem, using some sort of rolling cumsum structures in the for-loop. I have tried creating `numpy` arrays to "store" some previous calculated squared values inside the second loop in order to save some calculation time before, but to my surprise the change actually makes the function runs slower.

I can't help but feel that there's got to be some much better ways to implement the calculations that I am just not aware of it yet; or there could be small but important techniques to further speed up my code that I just don't know yet; or there are some `scipy` functions that do exactly what I am attempting to do but faster that I just don't know yet, which is why I am asking for help here.

---

Side Notes:

1) The `K` in `rt_mean_sq_dev4` is a correction term to improve the accuracy of the function by reducing the effect of catastrophic cancellation; this idea is inspired from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance)

---

EDIT1: forgot to type `np.sum()` in my original function `rt_mean_sq_dev`. That may have caused confusions to any readers to this question. My apologies

Comment: Did you consider trying “pandas.DataFrame/Series.roll.???” type functions? I cannot tell you if that would be faster or slower. But would be nice if you could try and report a comparison here.

Comment: @CypherX About at least 7x slower. It was pandas‘s slowness that made me want to implement it in numpy/numba in the first place.